# Problems with UINT values when testing with mocha/chai

Tags: solidity, truffle, mocha, unittesting

I am testing at the moment some smart contracts with truffle(mocha/chai/chai-as-promised) and have the following problem:

I have a getter, and this getter delivers an UINT value, then when I try to test the value with the `instance.getMemberCount().should.eventually.equal(4)` the result is: `expected { Object (s, e, ...) } to equal 4`.

Interesting fact is that when I try to compare the values directly with ‘==’ there is no problem.. (for example: `assert.equal(instance.getMemberCount() == 4)`)

Has Mocha/Chai problems transforming the uint values?

Comment: getMemberCount().toNumber() ? maybe

Comment: @ВиталийШвецов - there is no toNumber() in JavaScript or I am wrong? I have tried with Number(), parseInt() - but the result is NaN, because we have 'object Promise' and I am still stuck ..

Comment: @val3ri Web3 has a `BigNumber` object which has a `toNumber`. https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/ethereum_javascript_api.html see "web3.toBigNumber"

Answer (score 2):

You can use .valueOf() to get the return value from the getter function.

I've used this in one of the test cases I wrote sometime back.

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/Imaginea/lms/blob/master/test/testOrganisation.js#L31) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the github repository link I will search for answers there! 

With .valueOf() the result is: [object Promise]. And after printing the result is: { [String: '4'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 4 ] }. JavaScript is converting somehow this object and the comparison with "==" works.